# App crash, no idea why and how to fix it

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, webview, crash

I'm trying to fix the crash issue of a mac app. It's using the web view.
I got the report from fabric but I have no idea how to fix it.
Any suggestion?

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x00000000bbadbeef
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  JavaScriptCore                 0x7fff8d7a232e WTFCrash + 62
1  WebCore                        0x7fff879ca13d WebCore::DocumentLoader::detachFromFrame() + 269
2  WebKitLegacy                   0x7fff866f1f7e WebDocumentLoaderMac::detachFromFrame() + 14
3  WebCore                        0x7fff87945178 WebCore::FrameLoader::setDocumentLoader(WebCore::DocumentLoader*) + 104
4  WebCore                        0x7fff87ed90a0 WebCore::FrameLoader::transitionToCommitted(WebCore::CachedPage*) + 208
5  WebCore                        0x7fff87944a3d WebCore::FrameLoader::commitProvisionalLoad() + 397
6  WebCore                        0x7fff879e568d WebCore::DocumentLoader::commitLoad(char const*, int) + 77
7  WebCore                        0x7fff879e5254 WebCore::DocumentLoader::dataReceived(WebCore::CachedResource*, char const*, int) + 292
8  WebCore                        0x7fff879e4f51 WebCore::CachedRawResource::notifyClientsDataWasReceived(char const*, unsigned int) + 177
9  WebCore                        0x7fff879e4b2a WebCore::CachedRawResource::addDataBuffer(WebCore::ResourceBuffer*) + 170
10 WebCore                        0x7fff879e4802 WebCore::SubresourceLoader::didReceiveDataOrBuffer(char const*, int, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::SharedBuffer>, long long, WebCore::DataPayloadType) + 210
11 WebCore                        0x7fff87a08b0c WebCore::SubresourceLoader::didReceiveBuffer(WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::SharedBuffer>, long long, WebCore::DataPayloadType) + 44
12 WebCore                        0x7fff87a08a4a WebCore::ResourceLoader::didReceiveBuffer(WebCore::ResourceHandle*, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::SharedBuffer>, int) + 90
13 WebCore                        0x7fff87a08985 -[WebCoreResourceHandleAsDelegate connection:didReceiveData:lengthReceived:] + 101
14 CFNetwork                      0x7fff8552c81d __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 69
15 CFNetwork                      0x7fff8552c681 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 232
16 CFNetwork                      0x7fff8552c587 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 48
17 CFNetwork                      0x7fff85538f74 _NSURLConnectionDidReceiveData_LengthReceived(_CFURLConnection*, __CFData const*, long, void const*) + 83
18 CFNetwork                      0x7fff8552cf3b ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic29_delegate_didReceiveDataArrayEv_block_invoke + 297
19 CFNetwork                      0x7fff855e14a3 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 94
20 CFNetwork                      0x7fff8547feec RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*) + 72
21 CoreFoundation                 0x7fff9122c664 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
22 CFNetwork                      0x7fff8547fdad RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 133
23 CFNetwork                      0x7fff8547fb98 MultiplexerSource::perform() + 282
24 CFNetwork                      0x7fff8547f9ba MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 72
25 CoreFoundation                 0x7fff91260a01 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
26 CoreFoundation                 0x7fff91252b8d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
27 CoreFoundation                 0x7fff912521bf __CFRunLoopRun + 927
28 CoreFoundation                 0x7fff91251bd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
29 HIToolbox                      0x7fff82b9356f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
30 HIToolbox                      0x7fff82b932ea ReceiveNextEventCommon + 431
31 HIToolbox                      0x7fff82b9312b _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
32 AppKit                         0x7fff8acc88ab _DPSNextEvent + 978
33 AppKit                         0x7fff8acc7e58 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 346
34 AppKit                         0x7fff8acbdaf3 -[NSApplication run] + 594
35 AppKit                         0x7fff8ac3a244 NSApplicationMain + 1832
36 libdyld.dylib                  0x7fff896af5c9 start + 1
```

above is the log. Any idea why it happens and how to fix it?

Comment: enable zombies and check once

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365569/what-is-0xbbadbeef-used-for-in-webkit. It is the badbeef. Indicating may be your app running out of memory.

Comment: yea I think the memory leak may be the issue, thanks guys!!!